# Error in knockout js String is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi in my app when i click on addfields a form appears and when i try to submit that i am getting an error **String is not a function** . here is my code for add function

```
self.addTierFields = function (tier) {
   self.Tiers.push(new Tier({
                bothrate: self.bothrate(),
                compoundratee: self.compoundratee(),
                simplerate: self.simplerate(),
                rate: self.rate() 
   }));
    self.show(true);
};
```

and here is js fiddle link [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/b81mjt9k/9/)

Comment: `bothrate: self.bothrate()` <--- what do you think this line means? It's likely you're confusing the function invocation with passing a reference to it.

Comment: I think it's likely that some of mentioned properties is a string and not observable.

Comment: how can i solve this i just want to add the data on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.bothrate` etc are not knockout observables at the time they are accessed in your code. 
You have them defined in your html and they are just regular strings.

So try this instead:

```
self.addTierFields = function (tier) {
       self.Tiers.push(new Tier({
        bothrate: self.bothrate,
        compoundratee: self.compoundratee,
        simplerate: self.simplerate,
        rate: self.rate 
       }));
        self.show(true);
    };
```

Comment: Hi judgeja !! Thanks but i have one more question here is my js fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/c48sLdbc/ in this when you click on add new loan teram and then click apply it display showfields link on click of whick a list of fields appear when you click on edit it doesn't showing values in input field and display a error undefine is not a function can you please look into this. thanks in advance

Comment: You should use your browser developer tools to debug these sorts of things. You can set a breakpoint in the javascript and have a look at what all your variables are at the point where things go wrong. I set a breakpoint on the first line of the self.editTier function and discovered the following. These variables are undefined for your `LoadRateViewModel`, so cannot be used as observables: `self.compoundrate`, `self.bothrate`, `self.simplerate`, `self.tierIdentifier`, `self.rate`. See the added declarations in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c48sLdbc/1/

Comment: for that i have to use debug version of js ? currently m using min version

Comment: no, minified knockout is fine. I mean open the developer tools and debug (set breakpoints and examine values etc) YOUR javascript code. F12 on chrome for devtools. then go to sources and find your code in there.

Comment: i define them in Tier() then why i need to define them again in LoanRateViewModel ... i did it before without adding them in vmain view moel but in this i am getting error if i dnt define them

Comment: self in `self.editTier` refers to your `LoadRateViewModel` and not your `Tier` where you had them defined previously. `self.rate` inside `Tier` is NOT the same as `self.rate` inside your `LoadRateViewModel`. You can see you correctly define `var self=this;` for each of them separately.

Comment: H9i judgeja look into my this example in this i am not defineing the variable in main viewmodel still it is working http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/p4tuj5fa/

Comment: ?You aren't defining which variable there that you can still access? They all look defined to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet bellow

```
 self.Tiers.push(new Tier({
            bothrate: self.bothrate(),
            compoundratee: self.compoundratee(),
            simplerate: self.simplerate(),
            rate: self.rate()
  }));
```

There is no bothrate in LoanViewModel, I have also changed a number of things, understand the concepts of scope, meaning of $root,$parent,$data.

here is the new fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b81mjt9k/10/